# Objective-c: view background pattern

Tags: objective-c, view, background

Is it possible to have a pattern (say a grid) in a view that can be repeated x or y or both? Kind of like css:

background-image: url(pattern.png);
   background-repeat: repeat; //or repeat-x, repeat-y, no repeat;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can load an image pattern as a color (`[NSColor withPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"pattern"]]`) and then draw it as you would a regular color:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    ...
    // Load the image through NSImage and set it as the current color.
    [[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"pattern"]] set];

    // Fill the entire view with the image.
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:[self bounds]];
    ...
}
```

This code will repeat the pattern over the entirety of view, but you can have it simply x-repeat or y-repeat with a little modification.

---

Take a look at the [NSColor Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [NSView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 7):

The following code will tile a background image:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"background.png"]]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```